# How to pass Stream (C#) to ifStream (C++ CLI)?

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I have to pass in a C# stream object (I can read it from File or Amazon S3) to one DLL written in C++ CLI. The C++ file uses the ifstream type for this purpose. How do I pass it then?

I tried following this but could not understand much. 
https://oliversturm.com/2005/03/03/cds-csharp-extractor/

Comment: *I tried following this but could not understand much...* because its abaout COM's  IStream not cpp ifstream ... the easiest way is to save stream to a file on C# side and open ifstream from it on C++ side ... you may also try to extend ifstream and wrap c# stream there but this is to broad for SO

Comment: @Selvin hmm..Perhaps I might have followed the wrong link it seems. All I need is as per the title of the question and details minus that link (as it seems the wrong path to follow)

Comment: You need new class extending [basic_streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) which will bridge C# stream. This `streambuf` you can embed in a `std::istream`. Do not have time to provide details.

Comment: You need to use a pipe (which is  a stream) to connected the c# application to the c++ application.  There are two different types of pipes 1) Standard Input and Standout output 2) A named pipe.